# What is the correct way to distribute "bin" and "tests" directories for a Python package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils

I have created a python package.

At the advice of several internet sources (including https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject ), I have set up the directory structure like so:

```
root_dir
├── bin
│   └── do_stuff.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── my_lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── my_lib.py
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── important_script.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test_lib.py
```

I have included `tests`, `bin`, and `important_script.py` in the manifest, and set `include_package_data` in `setup.py` to True.

However, after running `pip install root_dir`, I see that it correctly installed `my_lib` but `bin` and `tests` were just placed directly into `Lib/site-packages` as if they were separate packages.

I can't find `important_script.py` at all, and I don't think it was installed.

How do I correctly include these files/directories in my installation?

**EDIT**

So, it turns out that the `bin` and `tests` directories being placed directly into the `site-packages` directory was caused by something I was doing previously, but I can't discover what.  At some point a `build` and a `dist` directory were generated in my `root_dir` (I assume by pip or setuptools?), and any changes I made to the project after that were not actually showing up in the installed package.  After deleting these directories, I am no longer able to reproduce that issue.

Comment: Show us your `setup.py`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample project distributes neither `bin` nor `tests`, it even [explicitly excludes `tests`](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/b0d3f3eeef4e5668d7b59448b43c0f1914d9afc6/setup.py#L133).

To include `bin` you should use [`scripts`](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts) or [`entry_points`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation) (like in the sample project). Add this to your `setup.py` to `setup()` call:

```
scripts=['bin/do_stuff.py'],
```

To include `tests` you should restructure your tree to include the directory `tests` under the package directory:

```
root_dir
├── bin
│   └── do_stuff.py
├── MANIFEST.in
├── README.md
├── my_lib
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── my_lib.py
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── test_lib.py
├── setup.cfg
├── setup.py
├── important_script.py
```

Comment: thanks for this.  I was able to get everything in `bin` and `tests`, as well as `important_script.py`, installed by using your directions.  I was not expecting my `bin` files and `important_script.py` to show up in `Scripts` instead of `Lib/site-packages`, but this will work.

Comment: *`bin` files and `important_script.py` to show up in `Scripts` instead of `Lib/site-packages`* That makes it simpler to add them to `$PATH`. You only need to add `Scripts` to `$PATH` once and every script after that will be in the `$PATH` automatically.